# Pandas dataframe increment by 1 every nth row and start again

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and there I want to create a new column with the following structure:

```
new_col
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
1
1
1
...
```

So starting again at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['new_col'] = (np.arange(len(df)) // 3 ) % 3 + 1
```

in general:

```
ll = len(df)
num_repeat, max_value = 3, 3
df['new_col'] = (np.arange(ll) // num_repeat) % max_value + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(11).reshape(-1, 1), columns=['a'])

n = 3
df.assign(
    b = np.take(
        np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(n) + 1, n), 1 + len(df) // n), 
        indices=np.arange(len(df))))
```

Output:

```
     a  b
0    0  1
1    1  1
2    2  1
3    3  2
4    4  2
5    5  2
6    6  3
7    7  3
8    8  3
9    9  1
10  10  1
```